# React generate table on submit multiple times

Tags: reactjs

I use the speedskatingsresults.com API. The user enters his name. This gives a skater ID and with this ID the personal records are retrieved and returned in a table.

I have three components. App.js, InputResults.js and Table.js. In InputResults.js I get the skater ID. In Table.js, the ID is used to retrieve the personal records.

**My problem is:**
For example, when I enter "Joeri Groot", I get a table with the correct results. When I enter a name for the second time, for example "Camiel Groot", the table remains instead of being replaced with the correct ID. Can someone help me with this problem?

```
InputResults.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Table from './Table';

class SkaterName extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            skatersList: '',
        };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    } 

    // Get the ID of based on the givenname and familyname in the input fields
    // Get the personal records by pasting the id in the Table component
    handleSubmit(event){

      event.preventDefault();

      const data = new FormData(event.target);
      let givenname = data.get('givenname').toLowerCase().trim().replace(/ {1,}/g," ").replace(/ /g,"+");;
      let familyname = data.get('familyname').toLowerCase().trim().replace(/ {1,}/g," ").replace(/ /g,"+");; 

      let url = `https://speedskatingresults.com/api/json/skater_lookup.php?givenname=${givenname}&familyname=${familyname}`;

      fetch(url)
      .then(skaters => {
          return skaters.json();
      }).then(data => {
          let skatersList = data.skaters.map((skaters, index) =>{

            return(

              <div>
                <ul key={index}>
                  <li onClick={this.onClick}> 
                    {skaters.id} {skaters.givenname} {skaters.familyname}
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <Table id={skaters.id}/>
              </div>
            )

          })
          this.setState({skatersList: skatersList});
      })
    }

    render() {

      return (
        <div className="container2">
            <div className="container1">  
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>Firstname:</label>
                <input type='text' name="givenname" value={this.givenname}/>  

                <label>Firstname:</label>
                <input type='text' name="familyname" value={this.familyname}/>

                <button>Send data!</button>
              </form>

              {this.state.skatersList}

            </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

export default SkaterName
```

```
Table.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Table extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            skatersLet: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){

        let url = `https://speedskatingresults.com/api/json/personal_records?skater=${this.props.id}`;

        fetch(url)
        .then(records => {
            return records.json();
        }).then(data => {

            let skatersLet = data.records.map((skater, index) =>{
                return(        
                    <tr key={index}>
                        <td>{skater.distance}</td>
                        <td>{skater.time}</td>
                        <td>{skater.date}</td>
                        <td>{skater.location}</td>
                    </tr>
                )
            })
            this.setState({skatersLet: skatersLet});
            console.log(skatersLet);
            console.log(url);
        })
    }

    render() {

      return (
        <div className="container2">
            <div className="container1">
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.skatersLet}
                    </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

export default Table
```

Comment: did the solution below work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your `Table` component is not updating is because you only make the request when the component mounts. This is a good opportunity to use React hooks.

If you use the [`React.useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook you can pass the `id` as an argument to the array which means it will exectute the code in the `useEffect` everytime the `id` is updated.

See code sandbox [example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-star-5kdwd) and relevant code snippet below implementing this:

```
const Table = ({ id }) => {
  const [skaterLet, setSkaterLet] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const url = `https://speedskatingresults.com/api/json/personal_records?skater=${id}`;

    fetch(url)
      .then(records => {
        return records.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        const skatersLet = data.records.map((skater, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{skater.distance}</td>
            <td>{skater.time}</td>
            <td>{skater.date}</td>
            <td>{skater.location}</td>
          </tr>
        ));
        setSkaterLet(skatersLet);
      });
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div className="container2">
      <div className="container1">
        <table>
          <tbody>{skaterLet}</tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't know why but I found out that I also had to make the variable skatersList a var instead of a let. Otherwise it won't work. Thanks for your help!